# Directives, Filters and Async Calls in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, filter, angularjs

I want to declare my own directive in AngularJS which takes as an attribute a string source of a file it must load and then modify in some way and display.

I have an AngularJS directive and filter defined as follows -

```
app.directive("customTag", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'src',
        scope: {
            value: "=src"
        },
        template: '<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="value | myFilter"></div>',
        replace: true
    };
});
app.filter('myFilter', function () {
    return function (value) {
        $http({
            url: value,
            method: 'GET'
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            value = data; // gets a string value
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            value = "Error getting content";
        });
        return ModifyString(value);
    };
});
```

And the corresponding HTML is -

```
<customTag src="/test.txt"></customTag>
```

However, this gives me an error saying that the `$http` is not defined in the scope. How do I fix this?

Furthermore, I think that I will run into the problem that `$http` call will be an asynchronous one, so the filter will not return the correct value after the file has been read.

Comment: You're on the right track, looking at your code I see no reason for $http to be defined, but how have you tried to fix that? I would recommend familiarising yourself with how angularjs handles dependencies (like $http), you can start here : http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di . You're also right that $http will be async, this is important because JS is single threaded and you don't want to block the browser. To solve that problem, I would recommend returning a promise, or adding a callback parameter.

Comment: can't return `ModifyString(value)` from your filter that contains `$http` request. AJAX is asynchronous so `value` will be undefined. Need to run `$http` elsewhere. Look through the tutorial on angular docs site for structure they use to make request

Comment: could you point me to some code which uses a promise in a filter?

Answer (score 3):

You need to inject `$http` provider in your filter provider:

```
app.filter('myFilter', function ($http) {...
```

That aside, you should reconsider your logic. Filters are not supposed to deal with server and promises. That's what services and directives are for.